# How can we improve traffic to the site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The site is [growing at an enormous pace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism).

So, how can we help increase its growth further and help make it a central repository of quality Buddhist resources and doubts.

Answer (score 6):

One idea would be cross-posting top questions and answers on the [Buddhism Reddit site](https://www.reddit.com/r/Buddhism/), which is very active with a huge community and excellent engagement stats.

I have cross posted [one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Buddhism/comments/3qe1xn/tibetan_buddhism_what_are_the_rotating_cylinders/), and it was well received and fared nicely there.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm never sure how these sites actually work - etiquette more than anything. Can you just post any question that you find interesting. There are loads of questions that have been asked on the site that are of interest. Can you just post it on? Is that the done thing? Thanks

Comment: @CrabBucket Yes, I have posted that question on the site just for testing on how well it would get receive, and it did a pretty nice job.

So, I think nice questions can be posted on that site.  Would help acquire users and increase traffic.

Comment: Also https://www.voat.co/v/theravada maybe an idea through not as active as Reddit.

Comment: I started it too. Good idea :)

Answer (score 3):

The [page which you linked to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism) says,

> Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

I suppose we have at least two jobs, i.e. to try to ensure that:

- Past and current questions are answered well (so that these questions and answers are helpful when people find them using search engines)
- The site retains a community of users who answer new questions

Comment: Yes i found the site in the same way and it has been a month since i joined